# Phalcon: Unable to initialize module on WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp, phalcon

I've been trying to instlal the phalcon framework on my local WAMP server, without succes. I get the following error in my `php_error.log` after I press "Restart all Services" in WAMP.

```
[07-Nov-2016 14:16:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: phalcon: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0
```

I've tried restarting the services multiple times, but without succes. I've also tried reinstalling WAMP server, but that dind't work either.

I could not find any relevant information or a good solution for my problem so that's the reason I'm posting here.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

I'm using php version `5.6.25` with phalcon version `x64 5.5.0_3.0.1`. I've installed Phalcon following [these](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/wamp.html) instructions.

Comment: what version of PHP? what version of Phalcon? How did you install Phalcon? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: Have you tried with the 32-bit dll? I think it depends on the version of Apache rather than the OS; I've not used WAMP but I had no problems getting Phalcon running on an (Windows) XAMPP dev box.

Comment: I've tried the 32-bit dll, when I do it gives me the following error: `[07-Nov-2016 14:57:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'd:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_phalcon.dll' - %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing.  in Unknown on line 0` Which translates to: `%1 Is not a valid Win32-application`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what I was doing wrong. I used `Phalcon 3.0.1 - Windows x64 for PHP 5.5.0 (vc11)` instead of `Phalcon 3.0.1 - Windows x64 for PHP 5.6.0 (vc11)`. Thanks everyone!

Comment: And that is why I asked for the PHP and Phalcon versions :)

Comment: Yeah, I was being stupid again. Thanks for your help though!